# linux: timeout in ioctl request to kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel, ioctl

I wrote a kernel module for an FPGA that generates an interrupt every N msec.

In the application, the code is:

```
ioctl(m_Handle, INTERRUPT_REQUEST_CODE,&Request);
```

In the kernel module, the case which handles this ioctl is:

```
case INTERRUPT_REQUEST_CODE:
    copy_from_user(&InterruptRequest, (void*)IoctlParam, sizeof(INTERRUPT_REQUEST));
    rc=wait_event_interruptible_timeout(sWaitQueuePacket, sInterruptFlagPacket != 0, Request.timeout);
    sInterruptFlagPacket = 0;
    InterruptRequest.Error = rc;
    copy_to_user(&InterruptRequest, (void*)IoctlParam, sizeof(INTERRUPT_REQUEST));
    
    break;
```

Is this the right way to be notified in the application about a timeout ?

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: Why don't notify a user about timeout via return value of ioctl?

Comment: You are right ! In kernel side, the return value of the ioctl handler is also the rc of ioctl in the application. Thank you very much .